# Is it possible to set css properties by id prefix?

Tags: css

Example

Set for all divs with ids starting `obj_` a black background color.

Is this possible just using CSS ?

EDIT

Ups I wrote class name in the title byt I ment Id name..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the CSS3 [attribute-starts-with](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors) selector:

```
div[id^="obj_"] {
    background: #000
}
```

This will work in all modern browsers.

Comment: good info, just keep in mind this is not supported or being buggy in many widely used browsers

Comment: There are some quirks in the support, but that exact example should work in IE7 and later, and all the other common browsers.